# What is the different between `Listen` and `ListenTCP`?

Tags: go

In Go, does `net.Listen("tcp", "127.0.0.1:9090")` not meet any needs? Why do we still have `net.ListenTCP("tcp", localAddress)`? I think they are much similar in implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Listen](https://pkg.go.dev/net#Listen) function is a common abstraction over [ListenTCP](https://pkg.go.dev/net#ListenTCP) and [ListenUnix](https://pkg.go.dev/net#ListenUnix).  The Listen function returns a protocol specific listener type as a [Listener](https://pkg.go.dev/net#Listener) interface.

Listen also provides the extra convenience of converting a string address to the specific address types required by ListenTCP and ListenUnix.

Use ListenTCP if you have [TCPAddr](https://pkg.go.dev/net#TCPAddr) in hand or need to use [TCPListener](https://pkg.go.dev/net#TCPListener) methods that are not available on the [Listener](https://pkg.go.dev/net#Listener) interface.

Answer (score 1):

`net.Listen()` returns an interface `net.Listener` that only guarantees it supports the following methods: `Accept()`, `Close()` and `Addr()`.

`net.ListenTCP()` returns a type `*net.TCPListener` that supports the above three methods so (duck typing) it supports the `net.Listener` interface. However, it also supports more functions that are specific to TCP and can control low level aspects of the connection acceptance. Things like setting `SetDeadline()` etc.